# Task scheduler has not enough rights when task are started automatically

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem with (possibly) the rights of the task scheduler. I have a batch(.bat) which looks like this:

```
@echo off
E:
cd "E:\batches\Check"
copy "Y:\file.txt" "checkFile.txt"
java -jar check_1.0.0.jar 
del checkFile.txt
exit
```

A simple batch which copies a file and starts a java-program which uses this file. When I click on the batch,

1. the batch is started (in the foreground),
2. the file is copied and
3. the program is started.

I have made a task in the task scheduler which starts this batch file. When I go to the task scheduler and select the task and click 'run':

1. the batch is started (in the foreground),
2. the file is copied and
3. the program is started.

And **here** comes the **catch/problem**. When I schedule the task to start automatically and the task is started following things happen:

1. the batch is started (in the background),
2. the file is NOT copied and
3. the Program IS started.

I know that the program has been started because of the exception of my program 'file does not exist'. So I assume that the automatic scheduler has not enough rights to copy the files? How can I give the right rights? Or is this an other problem I do not know about?

The Task is only started if the user 'Administrator' is logged in. OS is Windows Server 2016.

**EDIT**: The security options are:
When running the task, use the following user account:
domain\Administrator

'Run only when user is logged on' - Option is used

I have also tried to run the task with System account and tried the option 'Run whether user is logged on or not'.

**Solution**:
The solution which worked for me is:
Options enabled:

- Run only when user is logged on (User Account: domain\Administrator)
- Run with highest privileges

Can someone explain why in my case the 'highest privileges' are necessary?

Comment: run when admin is logged in is not the same as run task under... are task running under admin credentials, or under local or system account? are eirher `e` or `y` mapped devices? if first, change task account credentials, if second, make sure devices are available, put `net use …` or `pushd…` at the top of your batch script to make temporary mapping

Comment: @elzooilogico I have an edit to the credentials, I hope the EDIT clarifies some things, because I do not quite understand your questions regarding the credentials. `e` is a drive of the server itself and `y` is a mapped network drive. I will try using `net use ...` or `pushd...` (First I will learn how this is being used)

Comment: Mapped drive letters are not available in a non-interactive session. The easiest fix is to use the UNC path: `\\Server\share\folder\file`